# Lectura de archivos txt con PHP

Tags: php, txt, desarrollo

Hola estoy intentando extraer informacion de un archivo txt con PHP por ejemplo:

Linea 1: Luis Juarez

Linea 2: Paco Mendoza

Linea 3: Pepe Suarez

Me ayudaron anterioemente con esta sentencia

```
$arc = fopen('archivos/'.$nombre,"r");
while(! feof($arc))  {
    $Nombre = substr(fgets($arc), 0, 4);
    $Apellido = substr(fgets($arc), 6, 10);
      echo $Nombre;
      echo "<brs>";
      echo $Apellido;
      echo "<br>";
}
fclose($arc);
```

El problema es que cada vez que se ejecuta `fgets()` me manda a la siguiente linea y me imprime en pantalla Luis Mendoza cuando debería imprimir Luis Juarez, alguie me podria ayudar con la solucion
De antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes almacenar la línea retornada por `fgets` en una variable, y luego procesarla. También es mejor dividir la línea por el caracter en blanco `' '`, usando [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) porque el nombre puede tener cualquier cantidad de caracteres.

```php
$arc = fopen('archivos/'.$nombre,"r");
while(! feof($arc))  {
    $linea = fgets($arc);
    // eliminar salto de línea del final de la cadena
    $linea = rtrim($linea, "\r\n");
    $partes = explode(' ', $linea, 2);
    $Nombre = $partes[0];
    $Apellido = $partes[1];
    echo $Nombre;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $Apellido;
    echo "<br>";
}
fclose($arc);
```